# VueJS generating random "whitespace" in list loop

Tags: vue.js, dom, whitespace

I have this weird problem where my `v-if` loop generates a random `whitespace` in the DOM. I can also visually see it (see image). You see the whitespace to the left of the upload link. The code used to generate the links are pretty simple, but I cannot find out where the whitespace is coming from. Any ideas? Or am I doing something wrong? I tried to reset the cache also to see if that fixed it, but nope.

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item nav-brand">
                <router-link class="brand nav-link" :to="{ name: 'home' }">{{ this.$appName }}</router-link>
            </li>

            <template v-for="(link, index) in links">
                <li class="nav-item" :key="index">
                    <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{ name: link.name }">{{ link.title }}</router-link>
                </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>
```

And here is how I use the template:

```
<AppNavigation :links="[
    { name: 'upload', title: 'Upload' },
    { name: 'login', title: 'Login' }
]" />
```

```
<style lang="scss">

    // Import variables and mixins
    @use '../../scss/vars'; 
    @use '../../scss/mixins';

    .navbar {
        height:vars.$headerHeight;

        .nav {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            list-style:none;
            height:inherit;
        }

        .nav-brand {
            .brand {
                background:-moz-linear-gradient(-35deg, #33b2d9 0%, #e368f5 100%);
                background-size:100% 100%;
                transition:background-size .25s ease-in-out!important;
                            
                &:hover {
                    background:-moz-linear-gradient(-35deg, #33b2d9 0%, #e368f5 100%)!important;
                    background-size:100% 200%!important;
                }
            }
        }

        .nav-item {
            display:inline-flex;
            height:inherit;
            
            .nav-link {
                height:100%;
                display:flex;
                align-items:center;
                padding:0 20px;
                color:vars.$navLinkColor;
                font-size:vars.$navLinkSize;
                transition:background .05s ease-in-out;

                &:hover {
                    background:lighten(vars.$navItemBg, 5%);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a styling library or can you include the styles?

Comment: I am using the Normalize library globally, and I included the component style.

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox or live demo? It's easier for others to debug your code this way.

Comment: you have whitespace in the template, remove it, also place the v-for on the `li` remove the second template

Comment: @MajedBadawi I'll see if I can get the project up on a domain later. 
@LawrenceCherone Removed the extra template and added the for loop directly on the `<li>` element. No change. Also removed the whitespace in the template, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the problem by having a predefined `<li>` element. Then following that, a `v-for` on a `<li>` element. Like this:

```
<li ...>Test</li>
<li v-for="" ...></li>
```

The whitespace gets added above the `v-for`.

Solved it by just adding the brand to the list of links to be rendered, and removing the predefined brand element.